# Use ruby mechanize to get data from foursquare

Tags: ruby, mechanize, foursquare

I am trying to use ruby and Mechanize to parse data on foursquare's website. Here is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('https://foursquare.com')
page = agent.click page.link_with(:text => /Log In/) 
form = page.forms[1] 
form.F12778070592981DXGWJ = ARGV[0]
form.F1277807059296KSFTWQ = ARGV[1]
page = form.submit form.buttons.first
puts page.body
```

But then, when I run this code, the following error poped up:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.0.1/lib/mechanize/form.rb:162:in
`method_missing': undefined method `F12778070592981DXGWJ=' 
for #<Mechanize::Form:0x2b31f70> (NoMethodError)
    from four.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

I checked and found that these two variables for the form object "F12778070592981DXGWJ" and "F1277807059296KSFTWQ" are changing every time when I try to open foursquare's webpage.

Does any one have the same problem before? your variables change every time you try to open a webpage? How should I solve this problem?

Our project is about parsing the data on foursquare. So I need to be able to login first.

Answer (score 3):

Mechanize is useful for sites which don't expose an API, but Foursquare has an established [REST API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/overview.html) already. I'd recommend using one of the Ruby [libraries](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/libraries.html), perhaps [foursquare2](https://github.com/mattmueller/foursquare2). These libraries abstract away things like authentication, so you just have to [register your app](https://foursquare.com/oauth/) and use the provided keys.

Comment: As this is homework, using a pre-built API client may be cheating. On the other hand, it could be extra credit too :)

Comment: Depends on the assignment. Always best to be up front and discuss this with your prof.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of indexing the form fields by their name, just index them by their order. That way you don't have to worry about the name that changes on each request:

```
form.fields[0].value = ARGV[0]
form.fields[1].value = ARGV[1]
...
```

However like dwhalen said, using the REST API is probably a much better way. That's why it's there.